# Solving a matrix least squares problem with a fixed Frobenius norm constraint

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve for X an equation of the form :

Min ||AXB-CXD||  s.t. ||X||_F=1,

where , A, C are m-by-m matrices,  and B, D are n-by-b matrices. Is there any effective algorithms?

Any hint is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is equivalent to

$\min \| AXB - CXD \|_{F}^{2} $

subject to

$\| X \|_{F}^{2} = 1$.

Here, squaring the norms simplifies the calculations below without changing the optimal solutions.

The key idea is that this problem is really a linear least squares problem in the entries of the matrix $X$.  If you let the vector $u$ be defined by

$u=\mbox{vec}(X)=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
X_{1,1} \\
X_{2,1} \\
\vdots \\
X_{m,1} \\
X_{1,2} \\
X_{2,2} \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
X_{m,n}
\end{array}
\right]$

Then $\mbox{vec}(AXB-CXD)$ can be written as

$\mbox{vec}(AXB-CXD)=Gu$

where the entries of G can be computed by a tedious calculation.  In terms of $G$ and $u$, your problem is now

$\min \| Gu \|_{2}^{2}$

subject to

$\| u \|_{2}^{2}=1$.

This can be written as

$\min u^{T}G^{T}Gu$

subject to

$u^{T}u=1$.

This is simply the problem of finding a normalized eigenvector of $G^{T}G$ corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue of $G^{T}G$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply